# Stacking tr's within one table

Tags: css

I am trying to stack tr's in one table using z-index, but having no luck. I can't change/add to the structure itself so unless its vanilla javascript or CSS, my hands are tied. In my scenario, I need the 3rd tr to be behind the top 2 tr's.

```css
table {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

table tr:nth-child(3) {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

table tr:nth-child(1),
table tr:nth-child(2) {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      // Content
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      // Content
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      // Content needs to flow behind the other two on scrolling
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: for some reason, it worked itself out using what I have. I don't understand what was the difference

Answer (score 0):

Unless i'm understanding the issue wrong, I think this is what you want to achieve?

https://codepen.io/littlefinger42/pen/vvXbPZ

I havent changed any of your CSS, but i've corrected your HTML. `<tr>` elements require `<td>` or a `<tr>` as children.

Comment: td tags are there, I just didn't add them here

Comment: @Keith Is the codepen not what you're trying to achieve? I see three table rows on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your content into td's:

```css
<style type="text/css">
    table {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 100;
    }

        table tr:nth-child(3) {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        table tr:nth-child(1), table tr:nth-child(2) {
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 100;
        }
</style>
```

```html
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                // Content
            </td>
           
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
    // Content
</td>
           
        </tr>
        <tr> <td>
    // Content needs to flow behind the other two on scrolling
</td>
           
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables are a bit tricky to style because they aren't the typical `display: block` element like most html. Instead they are default to `display: table, table-row, table-cell`.

In order to get the `z-index` layering to work, you'll need to give the `<tr>`'s a `display: block` and also make sure you include your `<td>`'s in the `<tr>`'s so you keep things semantic. Then  you'll be able to achieve what you're looking to do.

```css
table{ }
table tr { position: relative; display: block; z-index: 1; }

table tr:nth-child(1)  { background: yellow; }
table tr:nth-child(2) { background: skyblue; }
table tr:nth-child(3) { background: lime; z-index: -1; transform: translateY(-50%); }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>td// Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>td// Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>// Content needs to flow behind the other two on scrolling</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```